# Multiple users for same AWS-EC2 account

Tags: user-accounts, amazon-ec2

Is there a way to use one AWS-EC2 instance by 3 (X) different users, without sharing the .pem file?

Update: Is it possible for 3 users to access 1 ec2 instance by their individual ID/password/.pem

Comment: this is question for webapps?

Comment: Serverfault, perhaps. not webapps.

Comment: Please the answer at http://serverfault.com/questions/300352/ec2-multiple-ssh-keys-for-an-instance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote my answer in detail here, comments welcome: [Manage multiple accounts on 1 Amazon EC2 Instance](https://medium.com/@utsengar/manage-multiple-linux-users-on-1-amazon-ec2-instance-5874ddf7e4b2)

Comment: Can you at least try to post some of that on here please rather than just linking to your own site - if you've read our FAQ you'll know we're trying to develop a shared knowledge base for all here.

Comment: well, my intention was not to publicize my blog. I first posted, the question, looked for an answer and then posted a blog post and then the answer here. AFAIK, posting a link rather than posting (copy-paste) a content directly from a website (duplication) is considered better.

Comment: Now your blog is not accessible. How painful...

Good example why you don't post links

Comment: Sorry about that, updated https://medium.com/@utsengar/manage-multiple-linux-users-on-1-amazon-ec2-instance-5874ddf7e4b2

Answer (score 0):

Create different user accounts in your instance, and you should be fine

Comment: but I will have to share the .pem file right?

Comment: Yes, unless you setup sshd to accept authentication using passwords - in which case you don't need separate user accounts either, (Note: password authentication is not a recommendation )

Comment: so, that was my question, is it possible for 3 users to access 1 ec2 instance by their individual ID/password/.pem

Comment: @zengr the ec2 instance is bound to a single amazon id, right ?

Comment: yes sir, but say, you have a development team and 2 of your software engineers need to push some thing to the same server, how will they achieve that? sharing .pem is not the right way.

Comment: I think this is what I am looking for: http://aws.amazon.com/iam/ Still in beta though.

Comment: answered my question.

Answer (score 0):

Use elasticfox:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/elasticfox/

Answer (score 0):

As expected: amazon does not restrict your EC2(expected good behavior) from having different user accounts which you can use to login to the instance.